# Gas Mileage Calculator Returning Negative

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the gas mileage. The function works but for some reason it returns a negative number, any solutions for this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gas Mileage</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function calcMPG(en,st,gal){
    var total= ((parseFloat(en) - parseFloat(st)))/(parseFloat(gal));
    document.milespergal.mpg.value = total;
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<h3>Gas Mileage</h3>
<form name="milespergal">
<p>Starting Mileage:<input type="text" value="0" name="start"><br>
Ending Mileage:<input type="text" value="0" name="end"><br>
Gallons Used:<input type="text" value="0" name="gallons"><br>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="calcMPG(document.milespergal.start.value,document.milespergal.end.value    ,document.milespergal.gallons.value)">
<br>
Miles Per Gallon:<input value="0" type="text" name="mpg"></p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have your parameters backwards. Try defining `calcMPG` as this:

```
//Reordered st & en
function calcMPG(st, en ,gal){
    var total= ((parseFloat(en) - parseFloat(st)))/(parseFloat(gal));
    document.milespergal.mpg.value = total;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppatino/hsv6L0a9/)